# Sending email from a kubernetes pod

Tags: email, kubernetes, smtp, grpc

I’ve built a service that lives in a Docker container. As part of it’s required behavior, when receiving a gRPC request, it needs to send an email as a side effect. So imagine something like

```
service MyExample {
  rpc ProcessAndSendEmail(MyData) returns (MyResponse) {}
}
```

where there’s an additional emission (adjacent to the request/response pattern) of an email message.

On a “typical” server deployment, I might have a postfix running ; if I were using a service, I’d just dial it’s SMTP endpoint. I don’t have either readily available in this case.

As I’m placing my service in a container and would like to deploy to kubernetes, I’m wondering what solutions work best? There may be a simple postfix-like Docker image I can deploy... I just don’t know.

Comment: please verify if it would be helpful [GO gRPC](https://medium.com/@matzhouse/go-grpc-and-docker-c1fb2ec8e9f0)

Comment: Thanks @Hanx, but no, that's not helpful. I'm already familiar with building Go gRPC services. My question is more centered on sending email from Kubernetes or an adjacent Docker container.

Comment: The [docker-mailserver](https://github.com/tomav/docker-mailserver/wiki/Using-in-Kubernetes) project may be the correct tool. Anyone familiar with that project care to answer?

Answer (score 1):

There's several docker mailservers:

- https://github.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver
- https://github.com/Mailu/Mailu
- https://github.com/bokysan/docker-postfix

Helm charts:

- https://github.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver-helm
- https://github.com/Mailu/helm-charts
- https://github.com/bokysan/docker-postfix/tree/master/helm

Note that the top answer in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/uf4r8v/easy_to_deploy_mail_server/) recommends signing up for a managed mail provider instead of trying to self-host your own.